# Flutter - Unhandled Exception: Error: Could not find the correct Provider<Database> above this SliverList Widget

Tags: flutter

so i have a question i got that error when i try to acces another page,i underatsn it have to do with the context but i do now know how to fix it.so what im trying to do is im trying to get to another page using the ontap widget, i can move just fine to antoher page i have created but when i try to move to this job entries it give me this error which i do not know how to resolve please help

heres the first page:

```
 import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:time_tracker_flutter_course/Services/auth.dart';
import 'package:time_tracker_flutter_course/Services/database.dart';
import 'package:time_tracker_flutter_course/app/home/job_entries/job_entries_page.dart';
import 'package:time_tracker_flutter_course/app/home/jobs/edit_job_page.dart';
import 'package:time_tracker_flutter_course/app/home/jobs/empty_content.dart';
import 'package:time_tracker_flutter_course/app/home/jobs/job_list_file.dart';
import 'package:time_tracker_flutter_course/app/home/models/job.dart';
import 'package:time_tracker_flutter_course/common_widget/show_alert_dialog.dart';
import 'package:time_tracker_flutter_course/common_widget/show_exception_alert_dialog.dart';

import 'list_items_builder.dart';

class JobsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  Future<void> _signOut(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      final auth = Provider.of<AuthBase>(context, listen: false);
      await auth.signOut();
      // onSignOut();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }

  Future<void> _confirmSignOut(BuildContext context) async {
    final didRequestSignOut = await showAlertDialog(
      //kalau awaitnya dihapus ngak dapat valuenya, cuman dapat 'Instance of 'Future<bool>''
      context,
      title: 'Logout',
      content: 'Are you sure want to log out?',
      defaultActionText: 'Logout',
      cancelActionText: 'Cancel',
    );
    print(didRequestSignOut);
    if (didRequestSignOut == true) {
      _signOut(context);
    }
  }

  Future<void> _createJob(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      final database = Provider.of<Database>(context, listen: false);
      await database.setJob(Job(
          name: 'Blogging',
          ratePerHour: 10)); //pakai bracket karena nerima map argument
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      print('$e.code');
      if (e.code == 'permission-denied') {
        /*handle permision error */
        showAlertDialog(
          context,
          title: 'operation failed',
          content: 'you dont have the acces to add new data',
          defaultActionText: 'ok',
        );
      }
    }
  }

  Future<void> _delete(BuildContext context, Job job) async {
    try {
      final database = Provider.of<Database>(context, listen: false);
      await database.deleteJob(job);
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      showExceptionAlertDialog(
        context,
        title: 'Operation failed',
        exception: e,
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Align(
          //busa pake align atau Center tapi Align cuztomizeable
          alignment: Alignment(0.4, -1),
          child: Text(
            'Jobs',
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text(
              'Logout',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            onPressed: () => _confirmSignOut(context),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: _buildContents(context),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () => EditJobPage.show(context),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildContents(BuildContext context) {
    final database = Provider.of<Database>(context, listen: false);
    return StreamBuilder<List<Job>>(
      stream: database.jobsStream(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return ListItemsBuilder<Job>(
          snapshot: snapshot,
          itemBuilder: (context, job) => Dismissible(
            key: Key('job-${job.id}'),
            background: Container(color: Colors.red),
            direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
            onDismissed: (direction) => _delete(context, job),
            child: JobListTile(
              job: job,
              onTap: () => JobEntriesPage.show(context, job),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

here's the second page i want to go to(the job entries page):

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:time_tracker_flutter_course/app/home/job_entries/entry_list_item.dart';
import 'package:time_tracker_flutter_course/app/home/job_entries/entry_page.dart';
import 'package:time_tracker_flutter_course/app/home/jobs/edit_job_page.dart';
import 'package:time_tracker_flutter_course/app/home/jobs/list_items_builder.dart';
import 'package:time_tracker_flutter_course/app/home/models/entry.dart';
import 'package:time_tracker_flutter_course/app/home/models/job.dart';
import 'package:time_tracker_flutter_course/common_widget/show_exception_alert_dialog.dart';
import 'package:time_tracker_flutter_course/services/database.dart';
import 'package:time_tracker_flutter_course/common_widget/show_alert_dialog.dart';
import 'package:time_tracker_flutter_course/common_widget/show_exception_alert_dialog.dart';

class JobEntriesPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const JobEntriesPage({@required this.database, @required this.job});
  final Database database;
  final Job job;

  static Future<void> show(BuildContext context, Job job) async {
    final database = Provider.of<Database>(context, listen: false);
    await Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        fullscreenDialog: false,
        builder: (context) => JobEntriesPage(database: database, job: job),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _deleteEntry(BuildContext context, Entry entry) async {
    try {
      await database.deleteEntry(entry);
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      showExceptionAlertDialog(
        context,
        title: 'Operation failed',
        exception: e,
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 2.0,
        title: Text(job.name),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text(
              'Edit',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.white),
            ),
            onPressed: () => EditJobPage.show(context, job: job),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: _buildContent(context, job),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () =>
            EntryPage.show(context: context, database: database, job: job),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildContent(BuildContext context, Job job) {
    return StreamBuilder<List<Entry>>(
      stream: database.entriesStream(job: job),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return ListItemsBuilder<Entry>(
          snapshot: snapshot,
          itemBuilder: (context, entry) {
            return DismissibleEntryListItem(
              key: Key('entry-${entry.id}'),
              entry: entry,
              job: job,
              onDismissed: () => _deleteEntry(context, entry),
              onTap: () => EntryPage.show(
                context: context,
                database: database,
                job: job,
                entry: entry,
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

[this is the job page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdlqJ.png)

the acces to the job entries page by clicking one of the job

[and this is the job entries page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vfm2a.png)

Comment: Have you mentioned the 'DataBase' provider above the 'JobEntriesPage'. Or you can post your entire code. That can help others to know the issue.

Comment: so i have included all of my codes, the problem is when the onTap: () => JobEntriesPage.show(context, job), i bring the context from jobspage to use it on JobEntriesPage, buat somehow when i run it it says could nor find the correct Provider<database> im really new on flutter im sorry.

Comment: So, what you want is to move to the other page i.e to 'JobEntriesPage' from 'JobsPage'. So, you do not need the show method in 'JobEntriesPage'. What you can do is take the entire body of the 'show' method & move it to the body of the onTap function.

Comment: If that is what you want & have a problem in implementing it, I can write an answer for you.

Comment: but if I put in the content of show in the body of onTap function, can i still use the other function in jobEntriesPge file? if yes, then yes please help me to figure this out .-.,becuase the first page and the second page using different files